# can I create a python gui and code at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

i am trying to build a GUI using Python but i don't know if i can use OpenCV. is it possible to create the GUI using only python and at the same time program image processing using OpenCV?

Comment: This question is too broad for SO, but yes, it is possible

Comment: thanks!! do you happen to know how? this is my first time working with OpenCV and Python..

Comment: You want to program a GUI and do image processing in parallel? This is very broad; you need to break down your problem into smaller pieces and ask them seperately. Ask yourself what you actually want

Comment: i want to create a image recognition/image processing using OpenCV-Python, but the GUI will be created using Python - tkinter. and i am wondering if it is possible for me to program the image recognition / image processing with the use of OpenCV-Python even if i am using Python - tkinter for the GUI?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this; you should just try and if you then run into a problem, ask a new question here